# Pointers on calculating probability/odds from data vectors

Tags: r, probability

I am trying to figure out how to calculate probability and odds for the variable Target.

```
Target <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
Treatment <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
Method <- c('A','A','A','B','A','B','C','A','A','B','C','C','C','B','A')

df <- data.frame(Target,Treatment,Method)
```

As an example I would like to be able to state something like:

- Method A increases your odds for success by 120%,
- Method B increases your odds for success by 15% and
- Method C decreases your odds for success by 20%.
- Treatment 1 increases your odds for success by 67%,
- Treatment 0 increases your odds for success by 35%
- Method A has a probability for success of 56%,
- Method B has probability for success of 33%, and
- Method C has a probability for success of 0%
- Treatment 1 has probability of success of 60%, and
- Treatment 0 has probability of success of 40%

An  pointers where to get started?

Answer (score 2):

These are all pretty basic manipulations:

Raw frequency table:

```
(tab0 <- with(df,table(Method,Target)))
##       Target
## Method 0 1
##      A 2 5
##      B 2 2
##      C 4 0
```

Probabilities:

```
(tab1 <- prop.table(tab0,margin=1))
##       Target
## Method         0         1
##      A 0.2857143 0.7142857
##      B 0.5000000 0.5000000
##      C 1.0000000 0.0000000
```

Odds for outcome of 1 vs. 0:

```
(odds <- tab0[,2]/tab0[,1])
##   A   B   C 
## 2.5 1.0 0.0
```

You can compute the overall odds:

```
(tab2 <- with(df,table(Target)))
(overall_odds <- tab2[2]/tab2[1])
##    1 
## 0.875
```

Odds ratios:

```
odds/overall_odds
```

The computations for `Treatment` will be more or less equivalent.

If you want to fit more complex, two-way models (additive or interactive effects), you should probably use `glm(...,family="binomial")`